# Django-graphos SimpleDataSource extension issue

Tags: python, django, charts

I'm building a django web app where I use graphos to add google charts to my app. I have a class CustomDataSource that is extending SimpleDataSource and I'm overriding the `get_data()` method and everything is working super fine and the charts were showing up.

Now I added an `__init__` constructor to my custom class to pass an extra variable that I need in `get_data()`. 
The constructor is being called fine and the variable is passed but for some weird reason, the `get_data()` method is never called and I cannot show the chart.

```
class CustomDataSource(SimpleDataSource):
    def __init__(self, data, wcs):
        super(CustomDataSource, self).__init__(data)
        self.wcs = wcs
        print self.wcs

    def get_data(self):
        data = super(CustomDataSource, self).get_data()
        print 'get data '
        # Build data to be returned and return it
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just made the extra variable optional:

```
class CustomDataSource(SimpleDataSource):
    def __init__(self, data, wcs = None):
        super(CustomDataSource, self).__init__(data)
        self.wcs = wcs
        print self.wcs

    def get_data(self):
        data = super(CustomDataSource, self).get_data()
        print 'get data '
        # Build data to be returned and return it
```

I don't know why this solved the issue but it did.